# Explanation to the following C# code

Tags: c#

```
    private Player _P1;

    public Character_Details(Player _Player)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _P1 = _Player;
    }
```

Our tutor never really explained this, basically I want to know what `P1 = Player` does and why it's necessary.

Essentially, I'm assuming that, say I call this constructor through another class:

Character Details CD = new Character Details(P1);

Providing that, previously, I've sent values to P1 before the call to the constructor was made, that, P1, when passed to the constructor, the object reference is passed to Character Detail's Constructor (_Player) which is then assigned to P1 via the constructor and then the values are stored within the private variable?

Is that correct?

Comment: I understand that the lack of coding conventions make this code seem poorly written, however, I will be changing the convention of the code to reflect better readability and understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P1 has been defined as a Private variable, that means it's only "visible" to the class it was defined in. This is generally good practice when you write code in an OO (Object-Oriented) design model and don't want other classes accessing your variable(s) directly.

The Character_Details method is public, which means other classes can execute the method once an instance of the class it is contained in has been instantiated (look up constructors if you don't know what this means). It takes a variable of the type Player. Once the P1 = Player line executes, the instance of the class which contains the P1 variable will have its reference set to the variable "Player" passed in to the method Character_Details.

The example code itself should be rewritten slightly, giving a variable a name exactly the same as it's type is not good practice. ("Player Player" should be "Player _player" or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

`P1 = Player` assigns the value of Player passed into the constructor to the field `P1` of the `Character_Details` object being created.

Comment: So, if I get that, when I pass an object variable to this class, it'll assign whatever values are in that object variable to P1 through player via the constructor?